# Android slide bar widget?

Tags: android, slider

Is there any slide bar widget to which i will place few icons and user can slide them it will role in and rol out from screen.

Comment: Can you better explain this question? I don't understand what you're trying to do. Perhaps linking to an example app or web page that does this can help.

Comment: Are you looking for something like shows up in the Market at the top to show the most popular apps and lets you scroll through them one at at time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're describing what I think you're describing, you're looking for the Gallery widget. This shows a horizontal row of icons that you can slide left and right past the edges of the screen, and at any time you can select any of them by tapping. I believe it also lets you show additional information about the one currently in the center.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for! Glad I found your comment. :-)